# Pass actions data in child component using react object

Tags: reactjs

I have a Navigation Panel(parent component) that has a Help and About button. On clicking About button, an About Dialog box is displayed with the version information of a product. The About Dialog is being defined in an explicit library and is just imported in the the parent component.

**NavPanel.js**

```
import { AboutDialogBox } from 'someotherlibrary';
const NavPanel = ({...props}) => {

return (
<AboutDialogBox
          shown={showAboutDialog}
          onClose={() => { toggleAboutDialog(); }} 
          actions={productVersion} />
)}
```

The catch is that content of the About Dialog has to be passed within the same repo where the parent component exists. The content of About Dialog box is being passed in the following format.

**AboutInfo.js**

```
const aboutInfo = {
    aboutInfo: [{
      type: 'header2',
      text: `Product name: ${pjson.version}`
    },
    {
      type: 'content',
      text: `About Content.`
    }],
    displayOrder: 3000
  };

  export default aboutInfo;
```

I would like to display dynamic version value in AboutInfo content that is currently being fetched by an action. A service has been created to fetch data from an api and the action is using that service and dispatching that data.

How do I pass data in AboutInfo file such that I can add it under content key of AboutInfo object ? Is it possible to pass action as props to AboutInfo ?

The render section of AboutDialogBox looks like the following:

**aboutDialog.js**

```
  render() {
        const { aboutList, shown } = this.props;
        const { list } = aboutList || {};
        if (list && shown) {
          const listOfAbout = list.sort((a, b) => {
            if(a.displayOrder < b.displayOrder) {
              return -1;
            }          
            else if(b.displayOrder < a.displayOrder) {
              return 1;
            }          
            return 0;
          });
          const aboutTitle = I18n.t("aboutDialogBox.aboutTitle");
          return (
            <Layer flush={true}
              closer={<Button a11yTitle="Close" style={{position:'absolute',cursor:'pointer',right:0}} onClick={()=>this.props.onClose()} icon={<Close />} />}
              onClose={this.onClose}
              id='about-dialog-layer' className='about-layer' key='layer'>
              <div className='dialog-container' key='dc'>
                <div className='about-container' key='ac'>
                  <div className='image' key='img'></div>
                  <Box className='content'
                    pad={{ vertical: 'medium', horizontal: 'medium' }} key='box'>
                    {this.loadCurrentComponent({ type: 'header1', text: aboutTitle },
                      'h1')}
                    {listOfAbout.map((listElement, index) =>
                      this.loadAbout(listElement.aboutInfo, index)
                    )}
                    {this.loadCommonText()}
                  </Box>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Layer>
          );
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
```

I tried to pass action as a parameter but its not able to read the value. Any suggestions would be a great help.  Thanks!

Comment: where are you passing the action from to the child component? you seem to have shown, onClose and actions as props for the about dialog box component. When you say parameter, are you referring to a URL parameter or parameter as in component props?

Comment: No, I mean parameter in component props!  I am passing action as a parameter to AboutDialogBox. Is that correct is my question ? Or is there a better/right way to do it ?